# How to run a sharable service indefinitely in android?

Tags: android, android-service

I want to create a library which has a service to read values from temperature sensors and do some processing. The service will be kept on monitoring the sensor values and give an alert if a high value is detected. I want to build several apps using this library. I am planning to add my library as a dependency to each app and if one app has started my service say "TemperatureService" then the other apps should consume that same service without creating a new one.

Further, when the service is started it should run indefinitely. And when I run a new app in future it should be able to bind to the currently running service.

I tried to use the IntentService but when I kill my app the service also stops.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this.getBaseContext(), MyTestService.class);
i.putExtra("foo", "bar");
startService(i);
```

How can I solve my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use started service rather using `IntentService` Because Intent Service stops itself after work is done.

So if you want to run service continuously you need to create service and with return value STICKY from `OnServiceConnected()` method that is callback method in Service class.

And For communication across multiple Application, you need to implement AIDL
and share the same interface to communicate with your application.

[Android Interface Definition Language (AIDL)](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwinm9jX6JTVAhWBJ5QKHRh3Ac8QFggvMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fguide%2Fcomponents%2Faidl.html&usg=AFQjCNEfLxCJRTCENVxp62iFG9ueMmOEeA)

> Aidl implementation
>
> Services implemented
>
> IPC in android
>
> Local call implemented

[Android Interface Definition Language (AIDL) and Remote Service](https://dzone.com/articles/android-interface-definition)

Above link has full demo how to create and use Service and AIDL for interprocess communication example use two application but you can create multiple Client Application.

Comment: How can I make the service shareable? One app could start the service and then all the apps start after it should be able to access the same Service. But when I call bindService from different apps it creates a new instance of the service.

Comment: @chamathabeysinghe See my updated Answer with Link having a small demo.

Answer (score 1):

for this purpose you have to use Android Interface Definition Language, and interprocess communication (IPC) for detail follow [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html)